# "TypeError: Argument 1 of ... is not a finite floating-point value" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a javascript code for clicking in mouse position (x/y)

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint( cursorX,cursorY );

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked')
}, false);

var support = true;

try {
    if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false}).bubbles !== false) {
        support = false;
    } else if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}).bubbles !== true) {
        support = false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    support = false;
}
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
cursorX = 0; cursorY = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.clientX;
   cursorY = e.clientY;
   elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}
```

It works correctly in chrome but not in firefox .
when i put this code in firefox console , it says : **TypeError: Argument 1 of Document.elementFromPoint is not a finite floating-point value.**

what's this error ? and how can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError: Argument 1 of ... is not a finite floating-point value.` means that the function expects a number and you passed it something else.

To fix, you need to find the line this error was reported on, and check what the first argument to `elementFromPoint()` is (in this error message the arguments are numbered starting from 1).

If it's indeed not a number, fix that and the error will go away.

In your snippet, the very first line uses `cursorX`/`cursorY`, which are not initialized. If you use the same code when you get the error, that could be the reason.

Comment: @MehrshadFarahani I've already told you everything I could, based on the information you've provided so far. Without additional details from you, I'm afraid I can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.x || e.clientX;
    cursorY = e.y || e.clientY;
    elem = document.elementFromPoint(cursorX, cursorY);
}
```

Comment: not else . it doesn't work .. i can't understand why this code runs in chrome but not in firefox ???? any extensions for fix this error ? i really need to run this code in firefox :(

Answer (score 0):

`e` might not be defined/passed as a parameter in Firefox
it's often when dealing with events that people will also have

```
e = e || window.event;
```

stated in their function.
perhaps this will fix your problem